# Primary and Secondary Button Classes

Tags: buttons

I'm trying to style some buttons in a function (below) with the default WordPress button classes but the buttons are not being displayed (only the hyperlinked text is showing).

I also tried deactivated all plugins and switching to a default WP theme to see if the buttons would display, but this issue still persists. So perhaps there's an issue with the `a` tags or the classes themselves?

Here's the function:

```
add_filter( 'upme_profile_edit_bar','upme_profile_edit_bar', 10, 3 );
function upme_profile_edit_bar( $edit_buttons , $id, $params ) {
    $edit_buttons .= '<a class="button button-primary" href="http://myurlhere.com" >Custom Button 1</a>';   
    $edit_buttons .= '<a class="button button-secondary" href="http://myotherurlhere.com" >Custom Button 2</a>';
    return $edit_buttons;
}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please add additional information as [edit]s to your question - instead of comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use classes from the WordPress *admin* styles on the front end. However, those styles are not loaded. You have two options, one of which I wouldn't recommend.

### Way #1: Do this

What I *would* recommend is that you simply copy and paste the buttons styles you want into your [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) or custom CSS plugin ([example](http://jetpack.me/support/custom-css/), one of many).

Here's a first pass at pulling them out and cleaning them up:

```
.button,
.button-primary,
.button-secondary {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button,
.button-secondary {
    color: #555;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.08);
    vertical-align: top;
}

p .button {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.button:hover,
.button-secondary:hover,
.button:focus,
.button-secondary:focus {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-color: #999;
    color: #222;
}

.button:focus,
.button-secondary:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.button:active,
.button-secondary:active {
    background: #eee;
    border-color: #999;
    color: #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px -3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px -3px rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.5 );
}

.button-primary {
    background: #2ea2cc;
    border-color: #0074a2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(120,200,230,0.5), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(120,200,230,0.5), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button-primary:hover,
.button-primary:focus {
    background: #1e8cbe;
    border-color: #0074a2;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(120,200,230,0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(120,200,230,0.6);
    color: #fff;
}

.button-primary:focus {
    border-color: #0e3950;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(120,200,230,0.6), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(120,200,230,0.6), 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.button-primary:active {
    background: #1b7aa6;
    border-color: #005684;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.95);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

This has the advantage of:

1. Ensuring that even if WordPress changes the class names or styles, you keep your button styles.
2. If WordPress moves the stylesheet files, you still get the styles.
3. These are exactly what you want. The alternative is loading extra styles you don't need.

### Way #2: Don't Do This

Not quite sure why I'm even including this, but maybe it'll be useful for someone. The alternative is to load the WordPress button styles on the front end. This has all the disadvantages that are opposite of the advantages of Way #1 listed above.

To do this would require two things:
 1. Load the stylesheet.
 1. Change your markup as all the styles only work if they're wrapped in an element with the class `wp-core-ui`. (Which should tell you that loading these styles are not intended and a bad idea!

To load the styles, I'd do this in a child theme's `functions.php` file, a custom plugin, or an `mu-plugin`:

```
function wpse159952_load_wp_button_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse159952_wp_button_styles', includes_url() . 'css/buttons.css', array(), get_bloginfo( 'version' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse159952_load_wp_button_styles' );
```

Comment: Aha, that's exactly what I needed! I was pulling my hair out wondering why they weren't loading. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain the solutions in such detail. I really appreciate it!